# HTML5 Map won't call popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm currently developing a web application making use of phonegap. Bellow follows a piece of code where I make use of  image map, the ideia is to call a popup at the moment the user touches/clicks the determineted coordinate and let the popup handle the rest. But for some reason the POP UP doesn't appear.

Following is the Popup general structure:

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="itemVistoria" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" style="width:250px; height:330px">
  
   <div id="popupVistoria_seletores" style="margin: 0 auto">
     <div class="circle" style="background:#960 !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('A'); window.close();">A</a></div>
     <div class="circle" style="background:#09F !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('Q');">Q</a></div>
     <div class="circle" style="background:#9F3 !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('R');">R</a></div><br>
     <div class="circle" style="background:#309 !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('M');">M</a></div>
     <div class="circle" style="background:#F93 !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('C');">C</a></div>
     <div class="circle" style="background:#666 !important">
       <a href="#" onclick="appendItemVistoria('S');">S</a></div><br>
                                                   
    </div>
  
</div>
```

And here the HMTL MAP

```html
<img name="path850" src="img/vistoria/modeloAvaliativo3.png" width="879" height="590" id="path850" usemap="#m_path850"  /> 
<map name="m_path850" id="m_path850" > 
 <area shape="circle" coords="384,25, 16" href="#itemVistoria" title="vidro_lateral_traseiro_direito" id= "vidro_lateral_traseiro_direito" onclick="callItemVistoria('vidro_lateral_traseiro_direito', 'vidro_lateral_traseiro_direito')" target="_self"/> 
 [...] code continues with several lines of coordinates

</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

After forgetting this piece of code and getting to it, months later I noticed that  this TAG did not had support for the mark data-rel="popup", so instead of using and link to refer to the popup, I used the popup *open* method from jquery:

$('#idPopUp').popup('open')

So it became something like this:

][

Now it works just fine